# How to refactor a large set of queries used by 3 view methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5

I have a report being created on 3 different views (main, pre-view, and a layout-free plain HTML version for an auto email).   The report uses about 28 queries and for some of those queries I'm doing some logic before the query:

```
  sunday_this_week = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 1.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_1_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 8.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_2_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 15.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_3_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 22.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_4_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 29.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  @sunday_dates = [sunday_this_week,sunday_1_week_ago,sunday_2_week_ago,sunday_3_week_ago,sunday_4_week_ago ]

  sql = %Q{
           SELECT * FROM report_notes
           WHERE week_of IN(?)
           ORDER BY week_of ASC, market ASC, measure ASC
          }
  @performance_metric_notes = RptNote.find_by_sql([ sql, @sunday_dates ])
```

Some of the queries are really large and since 3 views need them, I have the same queries listed under three differenct controller mthods. There's a lot of lines in the controller (~1400 lines).

What would you do to refactor something like ( is it possible to have a single controller method with all the query setup logic and queries, that the 3 different view methods can call instead of each view method having a copy )?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would extract all of this code in a separate `Report` class.
Moving it to another controller action would still result in a huge controller. Plus, if there is a lot of logic to generate the report, the controller action is not the right place for it. It's a lot better if you can keep your controllers clean, just preparing variables for the views.

Just put your class in /lib, and in your controller actions you can call something like

```
report = Report.new params
@performance_metric_notes = report.performance_metric_notes
@other_performances = report.other_performances
...
```

You get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put it in the Report Model as a Method?

```
@performance_metric_notes = RptNote.get_my_custom_report
```

Comment: I don't think it's the best strategy on the long run, especially if he has a lot of logic. I don't like fat models personaly.

Answer (score 1):

as @Christoph said, if there is a lot of logic involved, implement this as a method in the model ; moreover you could implement this as a [scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) :

```
class RptNote < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.performance_metric_notes( past_weeks = 4 )
    # this will calculate the last sundays for this week + 
    # the nth past weeks, defaults to 4 :
    last_sundays = (0..past_weeks).map do |n|
      (Time.now.beginning_of_week - (1+n*7).days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end
    # this will return a relation. Using an array in a where clause 
    # renders a SQL IN selector.
    self
      .where( week_of: last_sundays )
      .order( :week_of, :market, :measure )
  end

end
```

... this would even let you refine the results by adding other clauses :

```
RptNote.performance_metric_notes.where( measure: something )
```

see [Railscasts #215](http://railscasts.com/episodes/215-advanced-queries-in-rails-3) for more info about relations and queries in rails 3

**edit :** wooops, my bad, just saw your question was on rails 2. The logic stays the same, except for the query.

There is more : if your controller actions use this a lot, you can set a [before_filter](http://railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M000259&name=before_filter) on the controller to auto-fetch the records :

```
before_filter :fetch_notes

def fetch_notes
  @notes = RptNote.performance_metric_notes
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your model :

```
scope :by_dates, lambda { |dates|
  where("week_of IN (#{sunday_dates.join(,)})").
  order_by("week_of ASC, market ASC, measure ASC")
}

def self.sunday_dates
  sunday_this_week = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 1.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_1_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 8.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_2_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 15.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_3_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 22.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  sunday_4_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 29.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  [sunday_this_week,sunday_1_week_ago,sunday_2_week_ago,sunday_3_week_ago,sunday_4_week_ago]
end
```

And in your controller :

```
RptNote.by_dates(RptNote.sunday_dates)
```